# Пишет перегрузка, объявлено где sin_cos(): Function() написано, что не так?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Function
{
  protected:
    double x, y;
  public:
    Function()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    Function(Function& p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
    }
    virtual  double Calculation(int) = 0;
};

class sin_cos : public Function
{
    sin_cos(): Function()
    {}
    virtual  double Calculation(int t)
    {
        y = sin(t);
        x = cos(t);
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Function* mas[5];
    mas[1] = new sin_cos;
    cout << mas[i]->Calculation(10) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как исправить "невозможно обратиться к private член"?

Comment: Сделать его `public` :)

Comment: Ой, да, невнимательность)

Answer (score 0):

Надо бы как комментарий, но там не поместится...
Пишет VС++ следующее:

> error C2248: sin_cos::sin_cos: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "sin_cos"
>
> error C2065: i: необъявленный идентификатор
>
> error C2227: выражение слева от "->Calculation" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип

Что именно из этого вам непонятно?

GCC ругается [примерно так же](http://ideone.com/Dh1mhd):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:40:18: error: ‘sin_cos::sin_cos()’ is private within this context
     mas[1] = new sin_cos;
                  ^~~~~~~
prog.cpp:26:5: note: declared private here
     sin_cos(): Function()
     ^~~~~~~
prog.cpp:41:17: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << mas[i]->Calculation(10) << endl;
```

`sin_cos` - конструктор в классе не объявлен как `public`, так что создать объект вот так

```
mas[1] = new sin_cos;
```

нельзя - нет прав доступа.  А потом нельзя воспользоваться

```
mas[i]->Calculation(10)
```

потому что не только значение `i` неизвестно, но и сама эта переменная не объявлена.

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли указать управление доступом `public` для конструктора класса `sin_cos` и виртуальной функции `Calculation`

```
class sin_cos : public Function
{
  public:
  ^^^^^^^
    sin_cos(): Function()
    {}

    virtual  double Calculation(int t)
    {
        y = sin(t);
        x = cos(t);
        return x;
    }
};
```

Также в main, я думаю, вы имели в виду индекс 1 вместо переменной i, которая не объявлена

```
    mas[1] = new sin_cos;
    cout << mas[1]->Calculation(10) << endl;
               ^^^
```

Имейте в виду, что индексы массивов начинаются с 0, а не с 1.